# Best Screen Resolution to test Android Game

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, screen-orientation, screen-resolution, aspect-ratio

I am building a game for Android. I want to test it for as many phone and tablet resolutions as possible. Can somebody tell me what are the main resolutions i need to test so that i can be assured of it running fine on all Android supported phones and tables.

I am looking for something like 1024x768... etc. This is because I can set the resolution in unity and test it on my screen.

Answer (score 1):

i got this off of here for android maybe this will help

```
xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp
Generalised Dpi values for screens:

ldpi Resources for low-density (ldpi) screens (~120dpi)
mdpi Resources for medium-density (mdpi) screens (~160dpi). (This is the baseline    density.)
hdpi Resources for high-density (hdpi) screens (~240dpi).
xhdpi Resources for extra high-density (xhdpi) screens (~320dpi).

Therefore generalised size of your resources (assuming they are full screen):

ldpi
Vertical = 426 * 120 / 160 = 319.5px
Horizontal = 320 * 120 / 160 = 240px
mdpi
Vertical = 470 * 160 / 160 = 470px
Horizontal = 320 * 160 / 160 = 320px
hdpi
Vertical = 640 * 240 / 160 = 960px
Horizontal = 480 * 240 / 160 = 720px
xhdpi
Vertical = 960 * 320 / 160 = 1920px
Horizontal = 720 * 320 / 160 = 1440px

px = dp*dpi/160
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test it inside the `Editor` it is better that you set an aspect ratio and rezise the window to your needs. This gives you a flexible tester instead of making static resolutions.